# Will move constructor always take place in initialization statements that involve auto in C++?

Tags: c++, initialization, c++20, auto, move-constructor

So currently I prefer this style of initializing an object in C++, for example:

```
auto t{ std::thread(hello) };
```

I don't know if there is any, even slightly, cost of executing here because according to my understanding, an anonymous object of type `std::thread` will be constructed first, then my local variable `t` will be move-constructed with that object. This means we have to perform 2 types of constructions to get my variable `t` ready.

Is this really true? If so, does the following style perform better?

```
std::thread t{ hello };   // only 1 constructor will be invoked
```

I am concerning with the standard of C++20.

Comment: You can check yourself the generated assembly, for example in Godbolt's compiler explorer.

Comment: @Ch3steR I know kinda vaguely about the copy elision, but as far as I'm concerned, the copy elision is involved only in return statements and statements with assignment operator. I think the first example above has nothing to do with these 2 situations.

Comment: @MatG I checked out Godbolt's compiler according to your suggestion and the only thing I can check is the number of lines of the 2 assembly versions (yeah, assembly is not something in my area of expertise). Surprisingly they are the same ( I checked with the MSVC v19 build tool). So maybe the compilers are smart enough to elide the redundant constructor calls.

Comment: Since C++17 prefer `auto t = std::thread(hello);` as there will be no copy or move as `t` is initialised inplace.  _"...if T is a class type and the initializer is a prvalue expression whose cv-unqualified type is the same class as T, the initializer expression itself, rather than a temporary materialized from it, is used..."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization

Comment: @RichardCritten If you copy that in an answer you'll have my upvote

Comment: @MatG - thanks but mu comment does not actually answer the question as asked.